# Is there an arrayEachWithIndex in underscore.m?

Tags: objective-c, each, underscore.m

I've looked at the documentation for Underscore and it looks like the javascript library has an eachWithIndex method but the objective c version doesn't. Is that true? Is there a reason for not making the index available in objective c?

Comment: Probably identical to using `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` no?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is as of a few days ago, however it's not available in the released pod spec yet. Well, it's not a `forEachWithIndex` but a `mapWithIndex`.

Here's an example:

```
NSArray<NSString *> *myArray = @[@"zero", @"one", @"two", @"three"];

Underscore.array(myArray).mapWithIndex(^(id obj, NSUInteger idx) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu:%@", idx, obj];
});

Underscore.arrayMapWithIndex(myArray, ^(id obj, NSUInteger idx) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu:%@", idx, obj];
});
```